# Problemas con multer y carpeta static con NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, multer, routes

Les comento que estoy intentando cargar productos a una colección en MongoDB desde un formulario en una vista de handlebars, las imagenes estan guardadas en /public/img, que es la carpeta estática de mi proyecto. El problema es que la ruta que se guarda en mis productos en MongoDB es '\\C:\fakepath\originalname', cuando lo que necesito es que se guarde con la ruta '/public/img/timestamp-originalname'

Estructura de archivos en Markdown:

```
    ├───public/
    │   ├───css/
    │   │   └───style.css
    │   ├───img/
    │   └───js/
    │       └───index.js
    │       └───chat.js
    ├───src/
    │   ├───dao/
    │   │   ├───dbManagers/
    │   │   │   ├───carts.manager.js
    │   │   │   └───products.manager.js
    │   │   └───models/
    │   │       ├───carts.model.js
    │   │       ├───messages.model.js
    │   │       └───products.model.js
    │   ├───db/
    │   │   ├───carts.json
    │   │   └───products.json
    │   ├───routes/
    │   │   ├───carts.router.js
    │   │   ├───chat.router.js
    │   │   ├───products.router.js
    │   │   └───views.router.js
    │   ├───views/
    │   │   ├───layouts/
    │   │   │   └───main.handlebars
    │   │   ├───home.handlebars
    │   │   ├───chat.handlebars
    │   │   └───realTimeProducts.handlebars
    │   ├───app.js
    │   └───utils.js
    ├───.gitignore
    ├───package-lock.json
    └───package.json
```

En utils.js tengo la configuracion de multer y la logica de guardado de imágenes:

````
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
    import { dirname } from 'path';
    import multer from 'multer';
    
    const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
    const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
    
    
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            // cb(null, path.join(__dirname + '../public/img'));
            cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'img'));
    
        },
    
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            const timestamp = Date.now();
            const uniqueFilename = `${timestamp}-${file.originalname}`;
            cb(null, uniqueFilename);
        },
    
        fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
            if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image/")) {
                cb(null, true);
            } else {
                cb(new Error("Solo se permiten imágenes"));
            }
        },
    });
    
    console.log(`dirname multer: ${__dirname + '\\static' + '\\img'}`);
    
    const upload = multer({ storage });
    
    export { __dirname, upload }´´´
    
    app.js contiene la lógica serverside:
    ```import express from 'express';
    import { __dirname } from './utils.js';
    import handlebars from 'express-handlebars';
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    import { Server } from 'socket.io';
    import path from 'path';
    // import productManager from './dao/dbManagers/products.manager.js'
    
    import productsRouter from './routes/products.router.js';
    import cartsRouter from './routes/carts.router.js';
    import viewsRouter from './routes/views.router.js';
    import chatRouter from './routes/chat.router.js';
    import messagesModel from './dao/models/messages.model.js';
    // import ProductManager from './productManager.js';
    import Products from './dao/dbManagers/products.manager.js';
    
    const app = express();
    const PORT = 8080;
    const httpServer = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on PORT ${PORT}`));
    const socketServer = new Server(httpServer);
    // const productManager = new productManager();
    
    //Settings de Handlebars
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine());
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
    
    //Route de static folder
    const staticFolderPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public');
    console.log('Ruta de la carpeta estática:', staticFolderPath);
    app.use('/static', express.static(staticFolderPath));
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
    //rutas
    app.use('/', viewsRouter);
    app.use('/realtimeproducts', viewsRouter);
    app.use('/api/products', productsRouter);
    app.use('/api/carts', cartsRouter);
    app.use('/chat', chatRouter);
    
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecommerce', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Conexión a MongoDB exitosa');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error al conectar a MongoDB:', error);
        });
    
    
    //CONFIGURACION DE SOCKETS
    const io = socketServer;
    
    socketServer.on('connection', socket => {
        console.log("Nuevo cliente conectado");
        const productManager = new Products('products');
    
        //Socket para agregar productos
        socket.on('addProduct', async (newProduct) => {
            try {
                const addedProduct = await productManager.save(newProduct);
                const updatedProducts = await productManager.getAll();
        
                io.emit('updateProducts', updatedProducts); // Envía la lista actualizada al cliente
                console.log('Producto agregado:', addedProduct);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error al agregar el producto:', error);
            }
        });
        
        //Socket para eliminar productos
        socket.on('eliminar_producto', async (data) => {
            const productId = data.productId;
    
            try {
    
                await productManager.delete(productId);
                io.emit('producto_eliminado', { productId });
    
                const updatedProducts = await productManager.getAll();
                io.emit('updateProducts', updatedProducts);
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error al eliminar el producto:', error);
            }
        });
    
        //Socket para chat:
        socket.on('chatMessage', (data) => {
            const { user, message } = data;
            const newMessage = new messagesModel({ user, message });
            newMessage.save();
    
            io.emit('message', data);
        });
    });
````

products.router.js la lógica de rutas de productos:

```
    import express from 'express';
    import Products from '../dao/dbManagers/products.manager.js'
    import { upload } from '../utils.js';
    import productsModel from '../dao/models/products.model.js';
    
    const router = express.Router();
    const productCatalog = new Products();
    
    // Rutas para productos
    router.get('/', async (req, res) => { //Consulta todos los productos
        const limit = req.query.limit;
    
        try {
            const products = await productCatalog.getAll();
    
    
            if (limit) {
                res.json(products.slice(0, parseInt(limit))); // Establecer el límite de productos a mostrar
            } else {
                res.json(products);
            }
            // }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al obtener productos:', error);// DEPURACION
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'Error al obtener productos' });
    
    
        }
    });
    
    router.get('/:pid', async (req, res) => {//Consulta productos por ID
        const productId = parseInt(req.params.pid);
    
        if (!productId || isNaN(productId)) {
            res.status(400).send({ error: 'ID inválido, debe ser un valor numérico' });
            return;
        }
    
        try {
            const product = await productCatalog.getProductById(productId);
    
            if (product) {
                res.json(product);
            } else {
                res.status(404).send({ error: 'Producto no encontrado' });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'Error al obtener producto' });
        }
    });
    router.post('/', upload.single('thumbnail'), async (req, res) => {
        const {
            title,
            description,
            code,
            price,
            stock,
            category,
        } = req.body;
    
        if (!title || !description || !code || !price || !stock || !category) {
            res.status(400).send({ error: 'Todos los campos son obligatorios' });
            return;
        }
    
        try {
            // const imageUrl = req.file ? `/static/img/${req.file.filename}` : '';
            // const file = req.file;
            const imagePath = `/static/img/${file.filename}`
            // Obtener la ruta de la imagen
            // const imagePath = path.join('public', 'images', file.filename);
    
            const product = await productCatalog.addProduct({
                title,
                description,
                code,
                price,
                stock,
                category,
                thumbnail: imagePath,
            });
    
            io.emit('updateProducts', await productCatalog.getProducts());
    
            res.status(201).send(product);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'Error al agregar el producto' });
        }
    });
    
    router.delete('/:pid', async (req, res) => {//Borrar prod por ID
        const productId = req.params.pid;
    
        let result = await productsModel.findByIdAndDelete(productId);
    
        if(result === null){
            return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Producto no encontrado'});
        } else {
            return res.status(202).send({ message: 'Producto eliminado con exito', data: result});
        }
    });
    
    router.put('/:pid', upload.array('thumbnail'), async (req, res) => {//Modificar un producto
        const productId = req.params.pid;
        if (!productId) {
            res.status(400).send({ error: 'Debe actualizar mediante un ID de producto' });
            return;
        }
        
        const updatedFields = req.body;
    
        try {
            const existingProduct = await productsModel.findById(productId);
            if (!existingProduct) {
                res.status(404).send({ error: 'Producto no encontrado' });
                return;
            }
            for (const key in updatedFields) {
                if (updatedFields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    existingProduct[key] = updatedFields[key];
                }
            }
    
            if (req.files && req.files.length > 0) {
                const imageUrls = req.files.map((file) => {
                    return file.filename;
                });
                existingProduct.thumbnail = imageUrls;
            }
            const updatedProduct = await existingProduct.save();
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'Producto actualizado con éxito', product: updatedProduct });
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'Error al actualizar el producto' });
        }
    });
    
    export default router;
```

realtimeproducts.handlebars es la vista con el formulario y sus productos:

````
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <h2 class="section-title">Agregar Nuevo Producto</h2>
    
    <form id="add-product-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <form id="add-product-form">
            <label for="title">Título:</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Ingresa título">
    
            <label for="description">Descripción:</label>
            <input type="text" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Ingresa descripcion">
    
            <label for="price">Precio:</label>
            <input type="number" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Ingresa el precio" required>
    
            <label for="stock">Stock:</label>
            <input type="number" id="stock" name="stock" placeholder="Ingresa el stock">
    
            <label for="code">Código:</label>
            <input type="text" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Ingresa el código">
    
            <label for="category">Categoría:</label>
            <input type="text" id="category" name="category" placeholder="Ingresa la categoría">
    
            <label for="thumbnail">Imágenes:</label>
            <input type="file" id="thumbnail" name="thumbnail" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg, .webp, .tiff" required>
    
            <button type="submit">Agregar Producto</button>
        </form>
    
        <h2 class="section-title">Eliminar Producto</h2>
        <form id="delete-product-form">
            <input type="text" id="productId" placeholder="ID del producto a eliminar" required>
            <button type="submit">Eliminar Producto</button>
        </form>
    
        <h1 class="page-title">Lista de Productos en Tiempo Real</h1>
        <div class="product-list-container" id="product-list-container">
            <ul id="product-list">
                {{#each products}}
                <li class="product-list-item">
                    <h3 class="product-list-item-title">Producto: {{this.title}}</h3>
                    {{!-- <p class="product-list-item-description">{{this.description}}</p>
                    <p class="product-list-item-price">Precio: ${{this.price}}</p>
                    <p class="product-list-item-stock">Stock: {{this.stock}}</p>
                    <p class="product-list-item-code">Código: {{this.code}}</p> --}}
                    <p class="product-list-item-code">ID: {{this._id}}</p>
                    <img src="{{this.thumbnail}}" width="50px">
                    {{!-- <img class="product-list-item-img" src="/static/img/{{thumbnail}}" alt="{{title}}" width="150px"> --}}
                </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/index.js"></script>```
    Por último, index.js contiene la lógica clientside:
    ```const socket = io();
    
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Conectado al servidor WebSocket');
    });
    
    //ACTUALIZACION DE VISTA PRODUCTOS
    socket.on('updateProducts', (updatedProducts) => {
        console.log('Actualización de productos recibida:', updatedProducts);
    
        const productListContainer = document.getElementById('product-list-container');
        productListContainer.innerHTML = `
            <ul id="product-list">
                ${updatedProducts.map((product) => `
                    <li class="product-list-item">
                        <h3 class="product-list-item-title">Producto: ${product.title}</h3>
                        <p class="product-list-item-code">ID: ${product._id}</p>
                        <img src="${product.thumbnail}" width="50px">
                    </li>
                `).join('')}
            </ul>
        `;
    });
    
    
    const addProductForm = document.getElementById('add-product-form');
    
    //AGREGAR PRODUCTOS:
    addProductForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const productData = {
            title: document.getElementById('title').value,
            description: document.getElementById('description').value,
            price: document.getElementById('price').value,
            stock: document.getElementById('stock').value,
            code: document.getElementById('code').value,
            category: document.getElementById('category').value,
            thumbnail: document.getElementById('thumbnail').value,
        };
    
        socket.emit('addProduct', productData);
    
        addProductForm.reset();
    });
    
    //ELIMINAR PRODUCTOS:
    
    document.getElementById('delete-product-form').addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const productId = document.getElementById('productId').value;
        socket.emit('eliminar_producto', { productId });
    
    });
    socket.on('producto_eliminado', (data) => {
        const productId = data.productId;
        
        const productListContainer = document.getElementById('product-list-container');
        const productToRemove = document.getElementById(productId);
        
        if (productToRemove) {
            productListContainer.removeChild(productToRemove);
        }
    });
````